# JIRA Structure Variables Based on Column Values

Tags: jira

I have a structure that allows me to maintain earned value through %-based tracking through milestones.  I have columns that showcase milestones for an activity (Mostly based on the states of an Action).  I have milestone columns.  Then I associate % values to sum up based on which milestone an action is on.

```
with weight1 = 0.6:
with weight2 = 0.2:
with weight3 = 0.15:
with weight4 = 0.05:
IF(MATCH(Summary, "*Formal*")=1; (weight1 = 0.2 AND weight2 = 0.4 AND weight3 = 0.0 AND weight4 = 0.4))
AND
IF(MATCH(milestone4; "*Done*"); weight1+weight2+weight3+weight4;
MATCH(milestone3; "*Done*"); weight1+weight2+weight3;
MATCH(milestone2; "*Done*"); weight1+weight2;
MATCH(milestone1; "*Done*");weight1;0)
```

The problem is that when the Summary has "Formal" in it, the weight values do not change.    Is there a better way to have conditional variable values based on a milestone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some back and forth with other JIRA users, we came up with this solution to this problem.  It was just a rearrangement of the syntax to force JIRA into utilizing the correct values.

```
with weight1 = IF(MATCH(Summary, "*Formal*")=1; 0.2; 0.6):
with weight2 = IF(MATCH(Summary, "*Formal*")=1; 0.4; 0.2):
with weight3 = IF(MATCH(Summary, "*Formal*")=1; 0.0; 0.15):
with weight4 = IF(MATCH(Summary, "*Formal*")=1; 0.4; 0.05):

IF(MATCH(milestone4; "*Done*"); weight1+weight2+weight3+weight4;
MATCH(milestone3; "*Done*"); weight1+weight2+weight3;
MATCH(milestone2; "*Done*"); weight1+weight2;
MATCH(milestone1; "*Done*");weight1;0)
```

I have tested this in my structure and it works perfectly.